# Hadoop Hive IN Statement from file

Tags: hadoop, hive

Recently, the company I work for has moved some of it's long term storage to Hadoop and Hive.

I have a task where I need to query table_a for information, where table_b.unique is IN a text file.  This text file will be uploaded via a script prior to the query being started.

From my searches, it seems the ONLY way to do this is to load the data from the text file into a table, and then perform the query; however I do NOT have access to CREATE tables.

Is there any way to take this Hive query and change it from **table_B.unique = 'abcd1234'** to using an IN statement with a text file, without loading the file into a table first?

```
SELECT * FROM table_A 
JOIN table_B
ON (table_A.instancename = table_B.id AND table_B.unique = 'abcd1234');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't create any tables (not even external tables?) then I don't believe you can use hql.

You may be able to achieve this using [Pig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_%28programming_tool%29) Latin.